# Send coordinates via gprs to apache2 web server

Tags: python, json, webserver

I'm using BeagleBoard witch is connected to GPRS and I want to send 2 numbers (longitue and latitude) to web server on remote computer.
I was using ThingSpeak to do this and it works, but now i have to do it without any intermediary.
So on the BeagleBoard side i wrote this:

```
def doit(latitude, longitude):
    params =urllib.urlencode({'field1':latitude,'field2':longitude})
    headers ={"Content-type":"application/x-www-form-urlencoded","Accept":"text/plain"}
    conn = httplib.HTTPConnection("x.x.x.x",80)
    conn.request("POST", "/update", params, headers)
    response = conn.getresponse()
    print response.status, response.reason
    data = response.read()
    conn.close()
```

And it says:

```
404: Not Found
```

On my web server i have this part to recieve:

```
.....
$.getJSON('????',
                function(d){
                    var l=d.feeds.length;
.....
```

???? = IP from BeagleBoard?

Can someone please tell me how to send this coordinates and receive it on my server.

Server works fine, and it's not localhost, it has gateway IP.

Thanks